# Array not reseting in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, variables, ecmascript-6

I am running a Node+Express API that is working quite well, the only problem I have is when returning a complex query as a response, the variable to which I set the response to **is not getting reset between requests.**

It duplicates replies to the client such as replying 1, 2, 3 then the next reply replies 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3. So basically, it's concatenating data and not setting the `allPosts` variable to null again.

Here is my code:

```
var allPosts = [];
chirprdb.allPosts = (userData) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        userData.locations.forEach((location) =>{
            pool.query('SELECT posts.post_id, posts.title, posts.description FROM posts_locations INNER JOIN posts on posts.post_id = posts_locations.post_id WHERE posts_locations.location_id = ?', location.location_id, (err, results) => {
                if(err){
                    return reject(err);
                }               
                // allPosts.push(results)  
                results.forEach((result) =>{
                    allPosts.push(result)
                })                        
            });
        })
        resolve(allPosts)
    });
};
```

Comment: allPosts.push(result), just wondering, before you make a new request, check the values in allPosts array with a console.log.

Comment: This structure will never work because you will be calling `resolve(allPosts)` before `allPosts` has anything in it.  You will need to use the promise interface to `pool.query()` and then use `Promise.all()` with an array of promises like `return Promise.all(userData.map(location => pool.query(...)))`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Can you please give an example? I'm so lost with this.

Comment: What database are you using?  Does it have a promise interface instead of a plain callback interface?

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm using a MYSQL database.  Let me edit the OP and add the routes code.

Comment: I don't need the routes code.  I need to know the EXACT database library you're using so I can look up its promise interface.

Comment: @jfriend00 mysql db

Comment: This exact module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql?

Comment: @jfriend00 Yup. npm mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to program something like this is to use a promise interface on your database and then you can use promise-based tools for managing asynchronous operations.

The mysql2 module has a promise interface (that replaces the callback interface) and this function you have would look something like this:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

// returns a promise that resolves with a
chirprdb.allPosts = (userData) => {
    return Promise.all(usrData.locations.map(location => {
        return pool.query('SELECT posts.post_id, posts.title, posts.description FROM posts_locations INNER JOIN posts on posts.post_id = posts_locations.post_id WHERE posts_locations.location_id = ?', location.location_id);
    }));
}
```

But, I presume you need to change all your mysql programming over to the mysql2 promises interface.

There are also promise wrappers for the original mysql library such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-promise.

---

Your scheme does not work because you're calling `resolve(allPosts)` BEFORE anything has been added to `allPosts` and thus you're probably calling it again while it's still adding more things to `allPosts` and thus you feel like it isn't empty.  In any case, your current method is a timing disaster.

If you want to keep with the callback interface for mysql, then you have to implement some sort of counter that tells you when all your requests are done like this:

```
chirprdb.allPosts = (userData) => {
    let allPosts = [];
    let cntr = 0;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < userData.locations.length; i++) {
            let location = userData.locations[i];
            pool.query('SELECT posts.post_id, posts.title, posts.description FROM posts_locations INNER JOIN posts on posts.post_id = posts_locations.post_id WHERE posts_locations.location_id = ?', location.location_id, (err, results) => {
                if(err){
                    return reject(err);
                }
                ++cntr;
                allPosts[i] = results;
                // if all queries done now
                if (cntr === userData.locations.length) {
                    resolve(allPosts.flat());
                }
            });
        })
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put `allPosts` in `new Promise` block.

Comment: Where would it go, can you give an example please? I'm new to this and I just can't seem to get it right