# Node.js function not waiting despite async / await and Promise.all

Tags: mysql, node.js, async-await

I'm totally stuck with an async/await. I've tried multiple approach but cannot get what I need. Here is the situation :

```
async function mainfunction(){

var returned_result = [];

var client = mysql.createConnection(config);
    
client.connect(function(err){
    if(err){
      console.log('Error connecting to Db');
      client.end();}
});

var query_result = await client.query(sql, async function(err, rows) {

    ...

    var result = await secondFunction(client);

    ...

});

returned_result.push(query_result);
var returned_result_confirmation = await Promise.all(returned_result);
client.end();
return returned_result_confirmation;

}
```

My objective is to wait for the secondFunction to finish before calling client.end(); but it doesn't behave this way.

Would you have any pointer for me ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: `await` only does anything useful when you await a promise.  So, you have to make sure you're using an API that returns a promise if you want to use `await` with it.  To use promises with mysql, you will need mysql2 and then you will have to follow the directions in the doc for using it with promises.  And, you will not be passing a plain callback to an API that returns a promise (as that is redundant).  So, install mysql2 and read the doc on how to use it with promises.  Then, and only then, can you use `await` with it.  FYI, there are hundreds of other questions on this same topic.

Comment: Here's are some examples: [Array not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57701211/array-not-reseting-in-node-js/57702214#57702214), [Wait for DB to resolve promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60696945/wait-for-it-to-resolve-promise-and-then-insert-neatly/60697222#60697222) and [How do I wait for database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62256175/how-do-i-slow-down-my-express-server-response-to-allow-the-react-admin-getone/62256499#62256499).

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap this whole thing into a promise:

```
var query_result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    client.query(sql, async function(err, rows) {
        ...
        secondFunction(client)
            .then(data => resolve(data))
            .catch(err => reject(err))
        ...
});
```

or (not as nice I guess, but will also do it):

```
var query_result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    client.query(sql, async function(err, rows) {
       ...
       resolve(await secondFunction(client))
       ...
});
```

Comment: It would be better to obtain the version of this database that already has promise support built-in than manually promisify each db operation you want to use.  `mysql2/promise` has promise support built-in.

Comment: Definitely! Didn't know the framework so I went for the generic approach :-)